# .wsp/.cab file creation in SharePoint

Tags: solution-package, site-template

So I had to dismantle a .wsp file to correct some pathing issues that wouldn't fix any other way in feature.xml (this is a site template), and now can't seem to find a decent utility to put the .wsp/cab back together.  Is there any utility out there that can just take all the file and path information and rebuild the .cab similar to WinZip for example?  Makecab.exe seems to want a listing for every file (and it's a BIG template) and I can't find anything else out there.  And no WinZip doesn't do it any better.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't you have the original project files that created the WSP in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most highly praised, probably the most widely used, and personally my favourite SharePoint dev tool ever created is possibly your best solution to this.

WSPBuilder: http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/

You'd need to reorganise your folder structure of the WSP into what WSPbuilder expects, but this is probably your fastest way to do this.

We have recreated WSPs that we have been handed and needed to upgrade/patch up in the past, and it works really well.